# SolrCloud Indexing not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to index documents on SolrCloud on local machine with 3 ZooKeepers and 3 Solr Instances.I have installed Solr as service and my collection has 3 replication factor.Now I am indexing documents and if service of leader node is stopped then lots of documents are missed.But as per my knowledge SolrCloud gives Fault tolerance and high availability.So what could be the reason? give me suggestion what I am missing.

**logs**

```
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | 5600fce7-f6f8-4827-831b-1b9480f62355 | {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = 5600fce7-f6f8-4827-831b-1b9480f62355}
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory.finish | 5600fce7-f6f8-4827-831b-1b9480f62355 | [INDEXING_TEST_shard3_replica2] webapp = / Camino de Solr = / update queryId = 5600fce7-f6f8-4827-831b-1b9480f62355 params = {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 } {add = [6040]} 0 3
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | 6d8646b5-f909-4b9c-9cba-313081ef0ba6 | {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = 6d8646b5-f909-4b9c-9cba-313081ef0ba6}
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory.finish | 6d8646b5-f909-4b9c-9cba-313081ef0ba6 | [INDEXING_TEST_shard3_replica2] webapp = / Solr path = / update queryId = 6d8646b5-f909-4b9c-9cba-313081ef0ba6 params = {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 } {add = [6041]} 0 6
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | bc1911d6-e785-4b23-9730-127b3a751df5 | {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = bc1911d6-e785-4b23-9730-127b3a751df5}
[ERROR] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.a.solr.update.StreamingSolrClients.handleError | | error
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
en java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect (Método nativo)
en java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
en java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
en java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
en java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
en java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
en java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
en java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:589)
en org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket (PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
en org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
en org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open (ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
en org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
en org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
en org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute (AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
en org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
en org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
en org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient $ Runner.sendUpdateStream (ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:312)
en org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient $ Runner.run (ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:185)
en org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil $ MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda $ execute $ 0 (ExecutorUtil.java:229)
en java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
en java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
en java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | O.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory.finish | bc1911d6-e785-4b23-9730-127b3a751df5 | [INDEXING_TEST_shard3_replica2] webapp = / Camino de Solr = / update queryId = bc1911d6-e785-4b23-9730-127b3a751df5 params = {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 } {Add = [6042]} 0 14
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | Fa6f4db7-542e-41c2-8287-b0c3b9e0a272 | {Update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = fa6f4db7-542e-41c2-8287-b0c3b9e0a272}
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | O.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory.finish | Fa6f4db7-542e-41c2-8287-b0c3b9e0a272 | [INDEXING_TEST_shard3_replica2] webapp = / Camino de Solr = / actualizar queryId = fa6f4db7-542e-41c2-8287-b0c3b9e0a272 params = {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 } {Add = [6044]} 0 4
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | fba0324e-15d1-4752-ae05-fd67af5327e9 | {Update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = fba0324e-15d1-4752-ae05-fd67af5327e9}
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | O.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory.finish | Fba0324e-15d1-4752-ae05-fd67af5327e9 | [INDEXING_TEST_shard3_replica2] webapp = / Camino de Solr = / update queryId = fba0324e-15d1-4752-ae05-fd67af5327e9 params = {update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 } {Add = [6045]} 0 3
[INFO] | 08-04-2017 14:47:56 | | o.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.Request.preDecorateResponse | 9b57afc4-f906-4985-97a1-e3544e8feaec | {Update.distrib = TOLEADER & distrib.from = http: // devm50: 8091 / Solr / INDEXING_TEST_shard2_replica1 / & wt = javabin & version = 2 & queryId = 9b57afc4-f906-4985-97a1-e3544e8feaec}
```

Comment: How are you indexing? Where are you submitting your documents? What does the Admin interface say about your nodes? Is anything present in the logs? You have to provide some context for anyone to be able to give a valid answer.

Comment: I am importing data from database and reading text file from given path, I have created collection with replication factor of 3 and having 3 shards and also 3 instances of solr and zookeeper on single machine for testing purpose.if I do indexing it works properly only if all leaders are up but if in between indexing any leader node goes down then it takes more time to leader election. So, until this delay documents which should be indexed are missed.In logs connection refused error is shown because when sending the request to the node solr thinks that leader exists but actually it's not.

Comment: Here is the link of detailed question of this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830996/solrcloud-indexing-issue

Comment: hey Shubhangi , ty for suggesting edit